# What to do with a bounty: community wiki answer pasted from mathoverflow

Tags: discussion, mathoverflow, community-wiki, bounty

I'm not sure how or whether to award a bounty I started on [Double sum - Miklos Schweitzer 2010](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42624/double-sum-miklos-schweitzer-2010) - it's been answered by a mathoverflow user, and pasted into a community wiki answer by another mse user.

Any advice?

Comment: I wouldn't award it if I were you.

Comment: I can delete my answer, if you wish. Mac you could copy and paste the answer so that you get the bounty.

Comment: No, thanks for the offer, but I'm not too fussed really.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you award it, that user will get the reputation, regardless of community wiki status.

Beware auto-award thresholds.

If you *absolutely, positively* need to ensure that no user gets the bounty, flag it for mod attention with an explanation and a moderator can remove the bounty.

Comment: What is an auto-award threshold?

Comment: @mac the bounty will be auto-awarded in many circumstances; see http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty

Comment: oh, thanks. I guess in this case there is no absolute positive need to not award half the bounty in this way, so I'll probably just do nothing and let the system do its thing.